# Keep responsive divs side by side when one div contains a fixed size background image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

Needing to have 2 divs side by side
I have one div with a background image of 62px and the other div needs to take up the remaining container divs width.

Search-box1 will be the div that expands to fill the remainder of container search which will be at different sizes depending on what size screen its viewed on.

So i need the search-button1's size to stay at 62px width while search-box1 fills the remainder when containersearch stretches to fill responsively.

```
<div class = "containersearch">
<div class="search-box1"></div><div class="search-button1"></div></div>


.search-box1{
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #000000;
width:99%;
height:30px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
display: inline-block;

}


.search-button1{
background-image: url('search-button.png');
width:62px;
height:20px;
display: inline-block;

}

.containersearch


{border: 1px solid #006699;
background:#0A3D5D;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;

  width: 100%;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px; 

}
```

Comment: for now use this in .containersearch {display: inline-flex;}

Comment: I had my doubts that would work but it did :)

Comment: Would you know how to turn .search-box1 into a link now?

Comment: That will work, but the search button may resize slightly as you resize the screen, but I think it's definitely worth an up vote.

Comment: Why don't you try this ---> width: calc(100% - 62px);  for the div which you want to occupy the rest of the screen other than 62px.

Comment: are you using bootstrap for this ?? for making responsive design ??

Comment: it did resize a tiny bit but its an ok fix as the few px isn't an issue in this case

Comment: No bootstrap no

Comment: <div class="search-btn"><a href='#'><span class="search-button1"></span></a></div>
for search button as link try this. dont need to worry about  class="search-btn"

Comment: Thanks @mostafa baezid but i need the search box to be the link. How would i go about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use CSS calc() Function, something like

```
width: calc(100% - 62px);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Answer (score 1):

[https://jsfiddle.net/ns2352gt/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/ns2352gt/)

Maybe your looking something like this..

```css
  body{
    margin:0;
   }
   .containersearch
    {
    border: 1px solid #006699;
    background:#0A3D5D;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
     width:100%
     border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
     border-bottom-right-radius:8px; 
     }
    input[type=text]
    {
     position:relative;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 2px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 16px;
     background-image:
     url('http://findicons.com/files/icons/2226/matte_basic/32/search.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
     }

     input[type=text]:focus {
      width: 100%;
     }
```

```html
   
     <body>
      <div class = "containersearch">
       <form>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
       </form>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thats pretty cool but im trying to minimize page load time by serving an image that links off to a page with the google search on it. The image itself is of a search box and when a user clicks it to input text it takes them to the google search box page. So i need the search-box div to be a link. So like how you had the search button as a link, i need the search-box1 to be the link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/vy3evuof/ ok now check this one .. but its pretty bad idea. most of the user leave your site because of this. better Google
Custom Search API [https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction]  lets you develop websites and ... With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get either web search or image. Good luck

Comment: Thats actually really good. I dont get many searches to the google search api and its like over 150kb and tons of connections to load it. Decided to go with this approach instead. Works amazing in the fiddle but not showing up on my site. No idea why though.

Comment: Got it, was a duplicate class i missed. Thanks so much ive been wanting to do that for months. Works great :)